# SQL update multiple values for the same column based on value in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have three tables with connections between them, and want to update a value in one table based on a value in a different one.

Post columns: p_id, u_id, type
User columns: u_id (u_id in Post), f_id
Forum columns: f_id (f_id in User), type, value (f_id & type create a combined key)

Each forum can have multiple users. Users can only be in one forum.
Each user can have multiple posts. Post can only be written by one user.

A small DB example:
Post (p_id|u_id|type):
1|1|NULL
2|1|NULL
3|2|NULL
4|3|NULL
5|4|NULL

User (u_id|f_id):
1|1
2|1
3|2
4|3

Forum (f_id|type|value)
1|irrelevant_type_1|some_value_1
1|irrelevant_type_2|some_value_2
1|RELEVANT_TYPE|VALUE_1
1|irrelevant_type_3|some_value_3
2|irrelevant_type_1|some_value_4
2|RELEVANT_TYPE|VALUE_2
2|irrelevant_type_2|some_value_5
3|RELEVANT_TYPE|VALUE_1
3|irrelevant_type_1|some_value_6

Expected output:
Post (p_id|u_id|type):
1|1|VALUE_1
2|1|VALUE_1
3|2|VALUE_1
4|3|VALUE_2
5|4|VALUE_1

The type field in Post is new, and I want to update it according the the forum type.
I can get all forum types and than change for every type using

```
update Post set type = <VALUE> where u_fkey_id in (
  select u_id from (
    select distinct uid as u_id, f_id from User where uid in (
      select u_id from Post)) as t
    join Forum f on t.f_id = f.f_id where f.type = RELEVANT_TYPE and f.value = <VALUE>)
```

This works but will require me to iterate over all types manually.
Is there a better way to do this using native SQL?

Comment: What's your RDMS? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: @gotqn I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `inner join` to join your data, only no need of subqueries   :

```
update Post p
inner join User u on u.u_id = p.u_id
inner join Forum f on f.f_id = u.f_id
set p.type = f.type
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zFQPgj6T)

Comment: p.type should be set to f.value. Added a mini example of DB and expected output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, just changed f.type to f.value and added 'where f.type = TYPE' as a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something along the line

```sql
update Post
set
    type = (
        select
            f.type
        from
            Forum f
            join User u on (
                u.uid = Post.u_id
                and u.f_id = f.f_id
            )
    )
```

Will do. You structure is not very clear from your description, so check if correct field used for updating and joining.

Comment: p.type should be set to f.value. Added a mini example of DB and expected output to the question.